# ASP.Net core HTTP requests never reach my API, and wont redirect to HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I call my asp.net core API using an HTTP URL, the request never reaches my app, I've added a middleware to test this, and the request never hits the context. Though I've configured https redirection as I will show below, no Http request redirect to https.
But when I use an HTTPS URL, the request now hits my app.
I want to be able to call my API from Http URL then it redirects to https.

I've tried everything I saw on the internet. 
I tried enabling HTTPS redirection, but nothing worked. 
Here is what the https redirection looks like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else {
        app.ConfigureExceptionMiddleware();
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

IN the configureServices method:

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options => {
    options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status308PermanentRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 44382;
});
```

launchSettings.json

```
 "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53471",
      "sslPort": 44382
    }
  },
```

The code doesn't work and does not enable redirection. It only permits me to access my app via HTTPS, but redirection is not done.
Can anyone tell me how I can make a call to Http redirect to https?

Comment: Do you have other profiles in your launchsettings.json?

Comment: @John Code have you referred this - `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio`. It says `In development, set an HTTPS URL in launchsettings.json. Enable HTTPS when IIS Express is used.`

Comment: Thanks guys, you lead me on the right path. I have 2 profiles, and selecting the profile (in project settings) with the attribute: "commandName": "Project" resolved this issue

Answer (score 0):

What caused this problem was that I had two profiles in my Launch settings.json and I was chosing the wrong profile to launch the app.
Selecting the profile (in project settings) with the attribute: "commandName": "Project" resolved this issue. The guys in the comments on my answer lead me on the right track to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing HTTPS port, so your app should have logged error message `"Failed to determine the https port for redirect."`

You can configure the port using one of the following methods.

- Set `HttpsRedirectionOptions.HttpsPort`
- Set `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT` environment variable (Restart the computer to reflect changes)
- You can configure `https_port` port in appsettings.json file
  e.g:

  ```
    {
       "https_port": 443
    }
  ```
- Set an HTTPS URL in launchsettings.json

I hope one of these methods will resolve your issue!